# Why do I get this error? Unrecognized name: employees at [9:1]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've checked the tables, spelling, and retyped the code.

```
SELECT
employees.name as employee_name,
employees.role as employee_role,
departments.name as department_name
FROM
`my-project-practice-327821.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN 
employee_data.departments ON  
employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: give your table names an alias each

Answer (score 0):

You will need an `employees` to act as an alias after your fully qualified table name with backticks:

```
FROM `my-project-practice-327821.employee_data.employees` employees
```

Conversely, you could remove the backticks from your fully qualified table name:

```
FROM my-project-practice-327821.employee_data.employees
```

Comment: It worked, thank you ; )